Authentication problem in my React Project (First time using Authentication logic after learning firebase)
I almost finished a project I'm working on but I have an issue with Authentication, whenever I navigate to signUp or login page and I log in its working without any issue and I track the status of logging in or out the console says User X logged in, but when I navigate to any other pages it says User X logged out, here is the code logic in AuthContext
 `import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { auth } from '../config/firebase.config';
    import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordResetEmail, signOut, onAuthStateChanged, setPersistence, browserLocalPersistence } from "firebase/auth";

    const AuthContext = React.createContext();

    export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
    };

    export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const signUp = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    };

    const login = (email, password) => {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    };

    const logout = () => {
    return auth.signOut();
    };

    const getUser = () => {
        return auth.currentUser;
    }

    const forgetPassword = (email) => {
    return sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        setCurrentUser(user)
        setLoading(false)
    })

    return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    console.log("CurrentUser:", currentUser.email);

    const value = {
    currentUser,
    login,
    signUp,
    getUser,
    forgetPassword,
    logout
    };

    return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
        {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
    };
`



And here is the Sinup component

`import { Formik, Form, ErrorMessage, Field } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Card, Input, Checkbox, Button, Typography } from "@material-tailwind/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../../AppContexts/AuthContext';

const Signup = ({ onSignupSuccess }) => {
    const { signUp, currentUser } = useAuth();

    const initialValues = {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
    };

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const passwordRules = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{5,}$/;

    const onSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        setSubmitting(true);
        try {
            setError("");
            setLoading(true);
            await signUp(values.email, values.password);
            console.log("User signed up successfully");
            onSignupSuccess();
            navigate("/");
        } catch {
            setError("Failed to sign up");
            console.log("Sign up failed");
        }
        setLoading(false);
        setSubmitting(false);
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("user logged in:", currentUser.email);
    }, [currentUser])

    const validationSchema = Yup.object({
        name: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
        email: Yup.string().required('Email is required').email('Invalid email address'),
        phone: Yup.string()
            .required('Phone is required')
            .test('is-number', 'Invalid phone number', (value) => !isNaN(Number(value))),
        password: Yup.string().min(5).matches(passwordRules, { message: "Please create a stronger password" }).required("Password is required"),
        confirmPassword: Yup.string().oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], "Passwords must match").required("Confirm Password is required")
    });


    return (
        <div className="mt-24 p-10 flex justify-center">
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
            >
                {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                    <Card className="sign-up p-8">
                        <Typography variant="h4" className="text-white">
                            Sign Up
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography className="text-white mt-1 font-normal">
                            Nice to meet you! Enter your details to register.
                        </Typography>
                        <Form className="mt-8 mb-2 w-80 max-w-screen-lg sm:w-96">
                            <div className="mb-1 flex flex-col gap-6">
                                <div>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" className="text-white mb-3">
                                        Your Name
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Field
                                        name="name"
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Joe Doe"
                                        as={Input}
                                        size="lg"
                                        className="!border-t-blue-gray-200 focus:!border-t-gray-900"
                                    />
                                    <div className='error mt-1'>
                                        <ErrorMessage name='name' component='span' className='text-red-600' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" className="text-white mb-3">
                                        Phone Number
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Field
                                        name="phone"
                                        type="tel"
                                        placeholder="01xxxxxxxxxx"
                                        as={Input}
                                        size="lg"
                                        className="!border-t-blue-gray-200 focus:!border-t-gray-900"
                                    />
                                    <div className='error mt-1'>
                                        <ErrorMessage name='phone' component='span' className='text-red-600' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" className="text-white mb-3">
                                        Email
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Field
                                        name="email"
                                        type="email"
                                        placeholder="name@mail.com"
                                        as={Input}
                                        size="lg"
                                        className="!border-t-blue-gray-200 focus:!border-t-gray-900"
                                    />
                                    <div className='error mt-1'>
                                        <ErrorMessage name='email' component='span' className='text-red-600' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" className="text-white mb-3">
                                        Password
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Field
                                        name="password"
                                        type="password"
                                        placeholder="********"
                                        as={Input}
                                        size="lg"
                                        className="!border-t-blue-gray-200 focus:!border-t-gray-900"
                                    />
                                    <div className='error mt-1'>
                                        <ErrorMessage name='password' component='span' className='text-red-600' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" className="text-white mb-3">
                                        Confirm Password
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Field
                                        name="confirmPassword"
                                        type="password"
                                        placeholder="********"
                                        as={Input}
                                        size="lg"
                                        className="!border-t-blue-gray-200 focus:!border-t-gray-900"
                                    />
                                    <div className='error mt-1'>
                                        <ErrorMessage name='confirmPassword' component='span' className='text-red-600' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <Checkbox
                                label={
                                    <Typography
                                        variant="small"
                                        className="flex items-center font-normal text-white"
                                    >
                                        I agree the
                                        <a
                                            href="#"
                                            className="font-medium"
                                        >
                                            &nbsp;Terms and Conditions
                                        </a>
                                    </Typography>
                                }
                                containerProps={{ className: "-ml-2.5" }}
                            />
                            <Button type='submit' className="sign-btn mt-6" fullWidth disabled={loading || isSubmitting}>
                                Sign up
                            </Button>
                            <Typography className="mt-4 text-center font-normal text-gray-400">
                                Already have an account?{" "}
                                <Link to="/login" className="font-medium text-white">
                                    Sign In
                                </Link>
                            </Typography>
                        </Form>
                    </Card>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Signup;
`

I tried to navigate to other pages why logged in but it logs me out
